# Adding "K-" in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Please check my table

```
code        OutletCode
-----------------------
KL0000036   LFSRCP
KL0000037   LFSPTM
KL0000038   LFKTPB
KL0000039   K-LFGTBP
KL0000040   K-LFMKPM
KL0000041   K-LFMKRI
```

As you can see there are `K-` prefixes for some `OutletCode` rows. How to add `K-` to `LFSRCP` so the result will be `K-LFSRCP`?

I know I can do it with update one by one with this query

```
Update table 
set outletcode = 'K-LFSRCP' 
where code = 'KL0000036'
```

Comment: how large is the db? The answers will work with small to medium databases.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here: the answer you give seems to be the correct one.  Are you asking something different?

Comment: @JeffHornby I think OP missing the question: How can I process the update by batch instead of one by one?

Comment: sorry for late reply. i was working on my script. Felix Pamittan's answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update `OutletCode`s that do not start with `'K-'`, you can use `NOT LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET OutletCode = 'K-' + OutletCode
WHERE OutletCode NOT LIKE 'K-%'
```

This will add `'K-'` at the start of each `OutletCode` that does not start with `'K-'`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/478715)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET OutletCode = 'K-' + OutletCode
WHERE LEFT(OutletCode, 2) <> 'K-'
```

Comment: Is it `LEFT(OutletCode, 2)`?